# adding string and number together in php (FAULT!!)

Tags: php, string, numbers, addition, fault

I'm having little trouble with this code that reads ordernumbers from txt file, then adds 1 to that number. However PHP does not add these numbers together regardless of automatic type-casting...

```
    $handle1 = fopen("ordernumbers.txt", "r");
    $numberoforders = fgets($handle1);
    $numberoforders = trim($numberoforders);
    $orderid=$numberoforders+1;
    echo $orderid;
```

When echoing $numberoforders, it returns number 5 (type is string)

When echoing $orderid, it returns 1, while it should give 6.

I can not see any problem here, and it still does not work. I tried also to change that variable type from string to int, and then add these numbers together, but same result (1).

edit:here's the contents of the txt file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzk5C.jpg

Comment: What happens when you do this: `$orderid = ((int)$numberoforders + 1);` ?

Comment: The same thing happens, the result is 1

Comment: Just for completeness, can you please post the contents of `ordernumbers.txt` and the result of `var_dump($numberoforders)` please?

Comment: Than `$numberoforders` is not `'5'` at that time...

Comment: Ordernumber contains only one number:5 on the beginning of the first row. Var dump gives this: string(4) "5"

Comment: Try this and post output: `var_dump(base64_encode('5'));` and this: `var_dump(base64_encode($numberoforders));`

Answer (score 0):

Because $numberoforders is converted into integer and its value is 0, so 0 + 1 =1 that's  the output you are getting . If you want the string's characters number add to the integer value, you need to count the string's length first.

You can get your result like so

```
  $handle1 = fopen("ordernumbers.txt", "r");
  $numberoforders = fgets($handle1);
  $numberoforders = trim($numberoforders);
  $numberoforders  = strlen($numberoforders);
  $orderid=$numberoforders+1;
  echo $orderid;
```

Comment: actually i don't want to count how many characters are there in a string, just grab the number from the first line of the file, save it into variable and add 1 to it and insert result into new variable...

Comment: could you be more specific? which number you want to grab? of a string right? Aren't you getting your desired output?

Comment: ok I post the  code in bit details. Please tell me what is  the output.

Comment: ok, here goes: this is the number i want to store in a variable: http://imgur.com/bzjOuOJ . I would like to add one (1) to that number and store that new result into different variable

Comment: and the output with that code you posted above, is one.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, the above code is  working fine. I just wrote a  line like: 'this is string' into ordernumbers.txt file and the output is 15 cause first line of the text file is in length 14, so 14 + 1 = 15. what is the text in text file exactly

Comment: i do not want to count how many characters are there in the first file, i just want to grab the number from the first line... this number http://imgur.com/bzjOuOJ. For example, when the number in the txt file is 10, i want to get that number 10 into variable, add one to it and save the result to new variable...

Comment: If you add string with integer , it'll cast as a integer and if your string contains number that will be added to the integer value but if your string contains only characters then its value is 0 and 0 will be added to the integer value . what the string actually has can you show me?

Comment: the data in the text file does not contain characters, only one number at the beginning of the file, like this...http://imgur.com/bzjOuOJ, i have no idea why php reads it as character, while it is not...

Comment: I suspect you are doing something wrong then because I get 6 as the output if i put 5 into the ordernumbers.txt file . Are sure the text file is  in the same directory ?

Comment: i get 6 as well, if i put 5 into the file, but i should get also 8 when i put 7 inside text file, 9 when i put 8 etc... so we're having the same problem

Comment: Its not about  5, I mean everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As your var_dump gives `string(4) ''5''` to string stored in `$numberoforders` must contain three more characters.

I suspect a linebreak or something similar

Comment: actually there is not anything else than the number 5 (at least i have not put there anything else -> check the img)